# Is there a language which enforces "no escape" of variables?

Tags: programming-languages

Many languages with GC perform escape analysis to reduce heap allocations. Is there a language with a "no-escape" construct that tells the programmer during compile time to not escape certain variables? This way they could be guaranteed to be allocated on the stack instead of the heap.

Compare with value types in Java (not realized in any VM yet, AFAIK). In Go it's possible to debug and adjust the program to decrease heap allocations: https://segment.com/blog/allocation-efficiency-in-high-performance-go-services/

Comment: Sort of but not quite in the way you were thinking, check out Rust's lifetimes.